# What does an executable file contain when compiled by .NET?

Tags: .net, clr, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly happens when you run a .NET executable (step by step to the point where the program is loaded and running)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037399/what-exactly-happens-when-you-run-a-net-executable-step-by-step-to-the-point-wh)

I am kinda lost in terms of CIL, CLI, CLR...I would love to know how to process works when I compile and run my application.

At first the app is converted to CIL..is this the bytecode contained in the executable file? I would be so grateful for simple step-by-step description of running a .NET application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A summary can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).

Basically, when you compile your application, it is compiled into CIL (bytecode, previously known as MSIL). This is what is contained in your .Net dll, and you can see this bytecode using a tool like ILDASM or Reflector.

At runtime, the Just-In-Time compiler (JIT) compiles this into actual executable code which is native to your machine. In fact, using a tool called NGen, you can "pre-compile" native images so that your dlls actually contain native code, but this is a manual step and not done in most scenarios.

Comment: Native to my machine, ie machine code?

Comment: yes - processor specific machine code.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more qustion, you said DLL...that is the same for exe, right?

Comment: yes - absolutely. I should have said "assembly", not "dll" as it could be either.